# What is the difference between pd.value_counts(df['length']) and df['length'].value_counts()?? which one would be better?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

They both end up doing the same but which one is more efficient?[image]

I want to know the meaning behind them

Answer (score 1):

You should use `df['class'].value_counts()`.

`pd.value_counts` is undocumented, thus not guaranteed to remain accessible on the long term.

The two calls are equally fast:

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.choice(list('ABCD'), size=100000))

%%timeit
pd.value_counts(s)
# 8.59 ms ± 640 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
s.value_counts()
# 8.48 ms ± 357 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```